# Are two segments order isomorphic

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I thought  $[0,2]$ and $[0,1] \bigcup (2,3]$ are order isomorphic, since I can write the isomorphism $f:[0,2]\rightarrow [0,1] \bigcup (2,3]$ : $f(x)=x $ when $x\in [0,1]$
$f(x)=x+1$ when $x\in (1,2]$.

On the other hand, in $[0,2]$ every element has an immediate following element, and in  $[0,1] \bigcup (2,3]$ the element 1 doesn't have an immediate following element.

I am a bit confused. Are they order isomorphic or not, and why?

Comment: Please, be more specific and fix the latex.

Comment: What is the successor of $1/2$?

Comment: Oh, successor was the word I was looking for...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, in a real interval *no number ever has an immediately following element*. No matter which number you try to nominate as the immediately following element, there will be another one that is even closer.

$[0,2]$ and $[0,1]\cup(2,3]$ are indeed order isomorphic, for example by the correspondence you define.

Comment: I understand. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are [0,2] and [0,1)U(2,3] order isomorphic then?

Comment: @Whyka: No, because $[0,2]$ satisfies the property that every subset has least upper bound, but $[0,1)\cup(2,3]$ doesn't (in particular $[0,1)$ does not have a least upper bound). However, $[0,2]\cap\mathbb Q$ and $\bigl([0,1)\cup(2,3]\bigr)\cap\mathbb Q$ _are_ order isomorphic.

Comment: but is there a least upper bound to [0,1) in the $\cap\Bbb Q$ case?

Comment: No, but subsets of $\mathbb{Q}$ *don't* have the least upper bound property - e.g., $[0, \sqrt{2}]\cap\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @NoahSchweber okay, thanks! Can you please give me an example of a suitable isomorphic function? I find it problematic that the two segments are half open.

Comment: "I find it problematic that the two segments are half open" - basically, what you're being surprised by is the fact that that set (more generally, $\mathbb{Q}$) is **not connected**. A space is connected if it can't be broken into two disjoint open sets; $\mathbb{R}$ is connected (this actually takes proof!), but $\mathbb{Q}$ is not. Explicitly, we can write $\mathbb{Q}$ as the disjoint union of $(-\infty, \sqrt{2})\cap\mathbb{Q}$ and $(\sqrt{2}, \infty)\cap\mathbb{Q}$ - in some sense $\sqrt{2}$ is "missing," but since $\sqrt{2}$ isn't in $\mathbb{Q}$ this doesn't matter. (cont'd)

Comment: Such a splitting of $\mathbb{Q}$ is called a "Dedekind cut" - the real numbers, actually, can be built from the rationals by "filling in" all the Dedekind cuts! (Alternatively, $\mathbb{R}$ is the "metric completion" of $\mathbb{Q}$.) So if you think that spaces "ought to" be connected, basically what you're saying is: "I'm unsatisfied with $\mathbb{Q}$, and want to complete it to $\mathbb{R}$." This is a fine impulse! But you have to recognize that *not all spaces are connected.* (cont'd)

Comment: Anyways, that explicit isomorphism from $A=[0, 1]\cap\mathbb{Q}$ to $B=([0, 1)\cup (2, 3])\cap\mathbb{Q}$ you ask for: this is a bit messy actually. First, consider the map $f$ defined as follows: if $x<{1\over \sqrt{2}}$ (just picking an irrational number in $[0, 1]$, then $f(x)=\sqrt{2}x$; and if $x>{1\over\sqrt{2}}$, then $f(x)=(\sqrt{2}x-1){1\over\sqrt{2}-1}+2$. The first part of $f$ "moves" $A_0=[0, {1\over\sqrt{2}})\cap\mathbb{Q}$ into $[0, 1)$; the second part of $f$ "moves" $A_1=({1\over\sqrt{2}}, 1]\cap\mathbb{Q}$ into $(2, 3]$. This looks promising but doesn't actually work: (cont'd)

Comment: @Whyka: To define a concrete order isomorphism $[0,1)\cap \mathbb Q\to [0,\sqrt2)\cap\mathbb Q$, let $a_n$ and $b_n$ be increasing sequences of rationals that converge to $1$ and $\sqrt2$, respectively, such that $a_1=b_1=0$. For example let $a_n=1-1/n$ and let $b_n$ for $n>1$ be given by truncating the decimal representation of $\sqrt2$ after the first $n$ nonzero digtis. Now map each $a_n$ to $b_n$, and interpolate linearly between those points.

Comment: $f$ doesn't preserve rationality! So now we need to "smoosh" it around a bit, and this gets messy. As far as I know, there is no "snappy" isomorphism (EDIT: @HenningMakholm gives a much nicer example, but I'd still say it's not "snappy," quite). A much better, if less explicit, approach is to prove: any two countable sets of reals which are dense (between any two there's a third) and have no first or last elements, are homeomorphic. Then check that both $A$ and $B$ are countable, dense, and with no first or last elements. Even though this sounds un-explicit, it is actually fully constructive!

Comment: @NoahSchweber: Except the particular $A$ and $B$ here do have first and last elements (but that doesn't matter here, just map them to each other).

Comment: @NoahSchweber wow, the part about the connectedness and the Dedekind cuts was really interesting! Thanks a lot for introducing this to me and for your detailed answer.

Comment: @HenningMakholm nice solution, thanks!

Comment: @NoahSchweber What is the proof needed to show R is connected? It sounds like it is the very definition of connectedness in the real line...

Comment: Basically, it's the least upper bound property. However, if you're constructing the reals from the rationals, you need to show that the least upper bound property actually holds after you do the construction, and this is a bit tedious, and might be tricky if you haven't done any rigorous analysis before. (It's easy in retrospect, but doing it out all the way and not skipping any steps can be a bit hard for beginners.)